# ASP.NET hosting WCF Services, needs to increase MaxStringContentLength, but how?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, maxstringcontentlength

My ASP.NET server is providing a set of WCF services which are consumed by my WPF client. Everything was working just fine until the length of a string field exceeded 8K. This now generates the following exception on the ASP.NET server...

> There was an error deserializing the object of type Project.ModelType.
>   The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while
>   reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the
>   MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
>   object used when creating the XML reader.

I have increased the value of the *MaxStringContentLength* to be 64K on the WPF app.config but this has not solved the issue. So I guess I need to increase this value on the ASP.NET side as well. But I do not have any values in the web.config to change! Here is my web.config to show this...

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXFTOAUTH"
             timeout="10"
             slidingExpiration="true"
             cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So how do I update the server to indicate the higher *MaxStringContentLength* value? The app.config for my service looks like this...

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccess" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
               openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
               allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
               hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               maxBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="131072"
               messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
               useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <client>
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAccess" 
              contract="AccessService.IAccess"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccess" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

My services are defined by having a class 'Access.svc'

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Access : IAccess
{
    // ...IAccess method implementations
}
```

...which has the following markup...

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
                Service="Ecotech.AMS.WebServer.Access" 
                CodeBehind="Access.svc.cs" %>
```

...there is nothing specific about the service in the web.config, as noted in comments.

Comment: You must be missing something. That _can't_ be your entire web.config file. You have no reference to the service in there. How did you add the ServiceReference?

Comment: Not sure, so I don't post this as an answer, but the only value that is under the 8K limit is `maxBytesPerRead`. And the MSDN states `A positive integer that specifies the maximum allowed bytes returned per read. The default is 4096.` Try to increment this value

Comment: @Steve, he needs to set this value on the client as well, but the config file does not even have a reference to the service.

Comment: @ShaiCohen, right a whole section is missing in web.config, but the OP states the service was running well. So I assume that the missing piece is just something that has been lost pasting the web.config here.

Comment: Updated to show how my services are added. There is no binding or other mention of the services in the web.config file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking "Add Service Reference" via the right-click menu of your Project. Doing it this way will add the necessary configuration information into your web.config file.

Once you do this, you can set the `maxReceivedMessageSize` property on your binding. Doing it this way will most accurately reflect what you are doing on the WCF service side of things.

Comment: Right clicking my WPF project gives the 'Add Service Reference' option but right clicking the ASP.NET project does not. Note that ASP.NET is where the service is hosted and so I do not think adding a service reference to itself is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The place where you need to work on is the web config, you need to add service behaviours where you can set the size of data. For example like this,

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

if that does not work, post your web config here.Hope it helps.